# How do I get Version Control Tab to appear here in intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]

Where the terminal icon is I am trying to get Version Control to appear. For some reason it is not there.

Answer (score 1):

The "Version Control" tab has been renamed to "Git". It is the first tab you have on the left.